# MultiDataTrigger with Dependency Properties problem

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, multidatatrigger

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Switcher, Path=On}" Value="True"></Condition>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Switcher, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"></Condition>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <!-- Fire when IsMouseOver is set to true and On is set to true -->
    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>                                        
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="35" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="30 5 5 5" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <!-- Fire when IsMouseOver is set to false and On is set to true -->
    <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="30" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="35 5 5 5" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiDataTrigger>

<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Switcher, Path=On}" Value="False"></Condition>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Switcher, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"></Condition>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <!-- Fire when IsMouseOver is set to true and On is set to false -->
    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="35" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>                                                
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <!-- Fire when IsMouseOver is set to false and On is set to false -->
    <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="30" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>                                                
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

I have the following multi data triggers. The dependency property is also checked that's why I am not posting it here. I have comment to every data triggers enter and exit actions to what they are supposed to do. The second one is working just fine. However I can't get the first one working! Is there any possible way that the data trigger is working but my storyboard gets overridden

Comment: How are you setting these two `MultiDataTrigger` to your control(s)?

Comment: Using the ControlTemplate.Triggers

Comment: Have you tried the triggers separately? I think you're right that the storyboard gets overridden - after all, you have 2 triggers that happen at the same time (well, the EnterAction of one can happen at the same time as ExitAction of the other) and they both apply an animation to the same property of the same control.